# Can i use a method to change a variable that is external to it?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to change two booleans that exist outside my method. I read about passing by value and passing by reference and in this case i think the correct way is to use passing-by-reference.

However, it is not working. I call the method and my booleans still with the same value as before the calling.

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

`````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckingPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isClose = false;
    public bool isFar = false;
    public float radius;
    public float distance;
    private Vector3 initPos;
    private Vector3 actualPos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        initPos = this.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        actualPos = this.transform.position;
        Vector3 direction = actualPos - initPos;
        var distance = direction.magnitude;

        CheckPositionAndCount1(ref isClose, ref isFar);
    }

private void CheckPositionAndCount1(ref bool close, ref bool far)
    {
        if (close == false && far == false && distance > radius && distance != 0) 
        {
            far = true;
            Debug.Log("Saiu pela primeira vez");
            return;
        }
        else if (isClose == false && isFar == true && distance <= radius) 
        {
            far = false;
            close = true;
            Debug.Log("Está perto");
            return;
        }
        else if (isClose == true && isFar == false && distance > radius) 
        {
            close = false;
            far = true;
            Debug.Log("Está longe");
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
````
`````

Comment: Check your conditions in your function. You have mixed variables, this can create some confusion. Either only use the passed by ref function parameters, or the class variables.

Comment: Do you mind to expand on that? I'm new to programming.

Comment: You don't need to pass those two variables to that method, because both variables are defined on the class level. That means all methods of that class have access to those variables, just like `Start` and `Update`. You would need to pass those variables if you would call a method from *another* object. And when that method is supposed to change the values of those two variables, *then* you would have to pass them using the `ref` keyword.

Comment: Note that although you're working with Unity toward making a game, this is not a game development specific issue. It should generally be asked on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Vaillancourt's comment,

If you take a closer look at your `CheckPositionAndCount1` method, you'll notice that you have somewhere used `close` and `far` and somewhere `isClosed` and `isFar`. If you want to solve this problem using pass by reference then replace all the `isClose` and `isFar` with `close` and `far` respectively inside the `CheckPositionAndCount1` method. Like this,

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckingPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isClose = false;
    public bool isFar = false;
    public float radius;
    public float distance;
    private Vector3 initPos;
    private Vector3 actualPos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        initPos = this.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        actualPos = this.transform.position;
        Vector3 direction = actualPos - initPos;
        var distance = direction.magnitude;

        CheckPositionAndCount1(ref isClose, ref isFar);
    }

private void CheckPositionAndCount1(ref bool close, ref bool far)
    {
        if (close == false && far == false && distance > radius && distance != 0) 
        {
            far = true;
            Debug.Log("Saiu pela primeira vez");
            return;
        }
        else if (close == false && far == true && distance <= radius) 
        {
            far = false;
            close = true;
            Debug.Log("Está perto");
            return;
        }
        else if (close == true && far == false && distance > radius) 
        {
            close = false;
            far = true;
            Debug.Log("Está longe");
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
```

Another thing to note is that, class variables are available inside all the methods of the same class. So you can directly use `isClose` and `isFar` inside `CheckPositionAndCount1` without the need to pass them as arguments. Like this

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckingPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isClose = false;
    public bool isFar = false;
    public float radius;
    public float distance;
    private Vector3 initPos;
    private Vector3 actualPos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        initPos = this.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        actualPos = this.transform.position;
        Vector3 direction = actualPos - initPos;
        var distance = direction.magnitude;

        CheckPositionAndCount1();
    }

private void CheckPositionAndCount1()
    {
        if (isClose == false && isFar == false && distance > radius && distance != 0) 
        {
            isFar = true;
            Debug.Log("Saiu pela primeira vez");
            return;
        }
        else if (isClose == false && isFar == true && distance <= radius) 
        {
            isFar = false;
            isClose = true;
            Debug.Log("Está perto");
            return;
        }
        else if (isClose == true && isFar == false && distance > radius) 
        {
            isClose = false;
            isFar = true;
            Debug.Log("Está longe");
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
```

@WeckarE. correctly points out that using both `isClose` and `isFar` is redundant as `isClose = !isFar`. So you can essentially remove `isFar`, like this,

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckingPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isClose = false;
    public float radius;
    public float distance;
    private Vector3 initPos;
    private Vector3 actualPos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        initPos = this.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        actualPos = this.transform.position;
        Vector3 direction = actualPos - initPos;
        var distance = direction.magnitude;

        CheckPositionAndCount1();
    }

private void CheckPositionAndCount1()
    {
        if (isClose == false && distance > radius && distance != 0) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Saiu pela primeira vez");
            return;
        }
        else if (isClose == false && distance <= radius) 
        {
            isClose = true;
            Debug.Log("Está perto");
            return;
        }
        else if (isClose == true && distance > radius) 
        {
            isClose = false;
            Debug.Log("Está longe");
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: It also seems like the two boolean values are essentially each others' inverse. Having two variables code for the same thing...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, as I run the program, the variables (isClose and isFar) doesn't change to true or false according to the conditions. 
And if i copy the method content to the update content it works just fine... Do you know why it is happening?

Comment: I removed the condition 'distance !=0' from the first if and now it is working!

Answer (score 0):

The problem has something to do with the distance != 0 in the first if of the method. When i removed that it worked just fine.

Thanks for everyone that contributed.